# Are vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ of any rank completely classified? (main interest $n=3$)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

It is very well known that the group of line bundles on $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$ is exactly $\mathbb{Z}$. Are bundles of higher rank classified as well? If so, could anyone provide a nice reference, listing (some of) their invariants? If not, what are the incomplete results?

**Edit:** I learned that this is a hard open problem. Therefore i would like to restrict the question to the case $n=3$, i.e. "What are the (possibly incomplete) results on classification of vector bundles on $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^3$?"

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the classification of complex line bundles isn't special to $\Bbb C P^n$: complex line bundles are always classified by their first Chern class $c \in H^2(X; \Bbb Z)$ (at least for smooth manifolds, I don't know much algebraic geometry).

Comment: @Henry T. Horton: that's no longer true for algebraic isomorphism of line bundles. These are classified by the group Pic(X); it has a map to H^2 (first Chern class) but the kernel, written Pic^0(X), can be huge: in fact, it is itself an algebraic variety, of dimension equal to half of b_1(X).

Comment: @HenryT.Horton Well, i read this earlier today and i think that must be a rougher classification then the algebraic one. For example if one takes an algebraic surface $S$ with $h^1(S, \mathcal{O}_S) >0$ and $h^2(S, \mathcal{O}_S) =0$ then the natural map $Pic(S) \rightarrow H^2(S;\mathbb{Z})$ of line bundles to their Chern class is surjective but has a nontrivial kernel (which is in fact a   $h^1(S, \mathcal{O}_S)$-dimensional torus)

Comment: Oh hahaha @AsalBeagDubh thanks for your post, as you can tell i was writing my comment at the same time as you. Thanks for clearing that mystery up immediately!

Comment: @Joachim: great minds... By the way, I don't have time to answer now, but the short version is "definitely not": for example, it's an open conjecture whether every rank-2 bundle on $\mathbf{P}^n$ for $n \geq 6$ is a sum of line bundles. Google "Hartshorne's conjecture" to get started.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh, ah ok, thanks already! How about $\mathbb{P}^3$?

Comment: Almost the same question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20444/semiring-of-algebraic-vector-bundles-on-projective-space

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question, but maybe is worth a look. [This paper](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~fasel/vectorbundlesonthreefolds.pdf) classifies vector bundles on *smooth affine* threefolds. The methods are highly sophisticated.